# Rails 5. Wrong result in scope chaining

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have next models

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :user_tags
  has_many :children, foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: :destroy
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_tags
```

**user_tag.rb**

```
class UserTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :user
```

**child.rb**

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User'
```

In model user I have several scopes.

Select users, associated with ALL of required tags:

```
scope :search_by_tags, -> (ids) {
  joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: ids}).having('COUNT(tags.id) >= ?', ids.count).group('users.id') 
}
```

Which, generates next SQL request

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_tags" ON "user_tags"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "user_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."id" IN (17, 37, 70, 8, 11, 3, 91, 64) GROUP BY users.id HAVING (COUNT(tags.id) >= 8)
```

Other scope select users, associated with children in specific ages

```
scope :children_in_ages, -> (age_ranges) {
    joins(:children).where(children_ages_query(age_ranges))
      .where.not(children: {gender: -1}).group('users.id')
}

def self.children_ages_query(age_ranges)
    child_table = Child.arel_table
    range_conditions = age_ranges.map { |r| child_table[:birth_date].in(r) }
    range_conditions.inject(range_conditions.shift, &:and).to_sql
end
```

where `age_ranges` is array of dates. This scope generates next SQL query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "children" ON "children"."parent_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("children"."birth_date" BETWEEN '2016-02-29 08:35:00.322919' AND '2016-08-31 08:35:00.327283') AND ("children"."gender" != $1) GROUP BY users.id
```

Separately, scopes are working correct, but when I'm merging scopes, I have wrong result.

```
User.children_in_ages(a).search_by_tags(ids)
  User Load (85.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "children" ON "children"."parent_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "user_tags" ON "user_tags"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "user_tags"."tag_id" WHERE ("children"."birth_date" BETWEEN '2016-02-29 08:35:00.322919' AND '2016-08-31 08:35:00.327283') AND ("children"."gender" != $1) AND "tags"."id" IN (17, 37, 70, 8, 11, 3, 91, 64) GROUP BY users.id HAVING (COUNT(tags.id) >= 8)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You are not really "merging" scopes, you are making a "search" on top of the other search and by analysing output sql I can tell it works just fine. What is the intended result – you want to the result of both queries unioned in a one response?

Comment: @shlajin For example, `search_by_tags` returns users array with ids [1, 2, 3], `children_in_ages` returns users array with ids [2, 3, 4]. Expected result should be array of users with ids [2, 3]. So, yes, I need a union of both queries

Comment: I'm hardly trying to understand what are you trying to achieve with the `having('COUNT(tags.id) >= ?', ids.count)`, but I can not. What is the purpose of `search_by_tags` method? It's not just "show users, which are associated with specified tags".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution for my issue.

Proper way to select users with specific tags:

**models/user.rb**

```
scope :search_by_tags, -> (ids) { where(id: UserTag.users_with_tags(ids)) unless ids.blank? }
```

**models/user_tag.rb**

```
scope :users_with_tags, -> (ids) {
  select(:user_id).where(tag: ids).having('COUNT(user_id) >= ?', ids.count).group('user_id')
}
```

In this way, chaining with other scopes is working correct